# Append values in SQL

Tags: sql, append, teradata

suppose I have the next table.

I have the following problem when appending values ​​located in different rows.

```
rankk val price
1   A   10
2   B   20
3   C   30
```

How can I obtain this results?

```
rank val2
1    A
2    A,B
3    A,B,C
```

I'm stuck with

```
rank val2
1    A
2    ,B
3    ,C

create multiset volatile table tmp_db (
rankk integer,
val varchar(1),
price integer)
primary index (val) on commit preserve rows;

insert into tmp_db values (1,'A',10);
insert into tmp_db values (2,'B',20);
insert into tmp_db values (3,'C',30);

sel rankk,
        max(case when rankk = 1 then val else '' end) ||
        max(case when rankk = 2 then ',' || val else '' end) ||
        max(case when rankk = 3 then ',' || val else '' end) as val2,
        avg(price) as avg_price

from   tmp_db
group by 1;
```

Thanks in advance for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join like this

```
SEL t1.rankk,
        Max(CASE WHEN t2.rankk = 1 THEN t2.val ELSE '' end) ||
        Max(CASE WHEN t2.rankk = 2 THEN ',' || t2.val ELSE '' end) ||
        Max(CASE WHEN t2.rankk = 3 THEN ',' || t2.val ELSE '' end) AS val2,
        Avg(t2.price) AS avg_price

FROM tmp_db AS t1 JOIN tmp_db AS t2 
  ON t1.rankk >= t2.rankk -- include all previous rows
GROUP BY 1;
```

For higher ranks `xmlagg`can be used, too (this will add a space between values):

```
SELECT t1.rankk,
   Trim(Trailing ',' FROM 
       (XmlAgg(Trim(t2.val)|| ',' ORDER BY t2.val DESC) (VARCHAR(1000)))) AS val,
  Avg(t2.price) AS avg_price
FROM tmp_db AS t1 JOIN tmp_db AS t2 
  ON t1.rankk >= t2.rankk
GROUP BY 1
```

Depending on you actual data you might also use recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
 (
   SELECT rankk, val, Cast(val AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS rslt, price
   FROM tmp_db
   WHERE rankk = 1 -- start with 1st rank
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.rankk, t.val,
      cte.rslt || ',' || t.val AS rslt,
      cte.price + t.price -- to calculate average using sum/rankk
   FROM tmp_db AS t JOIN cte
   ON t.rankk = cte.rankk+1
 )
SELECT rankk, rslt, price / rankk 
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using recursive cte

```
with combo_data
  as (select rankk,val, cast(val as varchar(100)) as val2
        from tmp_db 
       where rankk=1
      union all
      select b.rankk,b.val,cast(concat(b.val,',',a.val2) as varchar(100))
        from tmp_db b
        join combo_data a
          on a.rankk+1=b.rankk
      )
select rankk,val2
  from combo_data
```